# Child and parents relations Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to create game something like jig-saw puzzle with Unity3d
I have two gameObj, each of them have empty Parent gameObj, when i am dragging them (childObj) to each other they stick to each other. I merge two ParentObj into one, which haves two childs(piece1 piece2). How add PolygonCollider2D to ParentObj from piece1 and piece2?

```
void CombinePieces(Transform piece1, Transform piece2) {

        if (piece1.parent != null) {
            //Debug.Log (piece1.parent.name);
                if (piece2.parent != null) {

                //Destroy(piece2.parent, 3.0f);
                }

                piece2.parent = piece1.parent;


                //here should be created new PolygonCollider2D which should have PolygonCollider2D  
                //from piece1 and piece2

                piece2.collider2D.enabled = false;
                piece1.collider2D.enabled = false;

            }

            else {

                if (piece2.parent != null) {
                    piece1.parent = piece2.parent;
                }

                else {

                    Transform trans = new GameObject().transform;

                    piece1.parent = trans;
                    piece2.parent = trans;
                Debug.Log("6");

                }
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GameObject.AddComponent` to add a Component to a GameObject.

You can do 
`piece1.parent.gameObject.AddComponent<PolygonCollider2D>();`

This function also returns the component itself, as explained in the Unity Documentation:
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html

Comment: yeah, but PolygonCollider2D should be from piece1 and piece2

Comment: what you mean with "should be from piece1 and piece2"?
you want get the PolygonCollider2D contained in the piece1 and piece2 to add to the ParentObj?
Maybe I've understood your question wrong.

Comment: you want get the PolygonCollider2D contained in the piece1 and piece2 to add to the ParentObj?
yes

Comment: In this case I think you can't exactly move the component itself, but you can use `GameObject.GetComponent` to retrieve the component and set the same properties to the new PolygonCollider2D